# Eliminate shake when using jQuery scrollTop

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I've got a function that scrolls down to the next section of an article when the down arrow on the keyboard is pressed and scrolls up when the up arrow is pressed.  Its working fine, however there is a slight "bounce" or "jitter" just before it scrolls.

I was able to partial fix for this problem by having the function return false, however, returning false swallows the key down event, leaving me unable use my keyboard to interact with the browser.

Any ideas on how to eliminate the "jitter" while at the same time freeing up my keyboard?

```
var $sections = $('.section');
var curr = -1;

$(document).keydown(function(e){
  prev = (curr < 0)? $sections.length-1: curr-1;
  next = (curr >= $sections.length-1)? -1: curr+1 ;

  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 38:  // up key
      s = $sections.eq(prev).offset().top;
      curr = prev;
      break;
    case 40:  // down key
      s = $sections.eq(next).offset().top;
      curr = next;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  } 

  if (curr == -1 ){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');
  }
  else{
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: s}, 'slow');
  }
  return e;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Yi...as an alternative...I just got it to work by setting the default switch case to return e. Then the return at the bottom of the function returns false.

The result looks something like this:

```
var $sections = $('.section');
var curr = -1;

$(document).keydown(function(e){
  prev = (curr < 0)? $sections.length-1: curr-1;
  next = (curr >= $sections.length-1)? -1: curr+1 ;

  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 38:  // up key
      s = $sections.eq(prev).offset().top;
      curr = prev;
      break;
    case 40:  // down key
      s = $sections.eq(next).offset().top;
      curr = next;
      break;
    default:
      return e;
  } 

  if (curr == -1 ){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow');
  }
  else{
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: s}, 'slow');
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I prefer this solution as it only tests for which key was pressed once and doesn't involve waiting

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you can simply add a simple `if` statement that will only execute the scrolling code if the `keyCode` matches up and down:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 38 || e.keyCode === 40) {
        // Your code
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here's a simple demonstration of this in effect: http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/SceDY/1/

---

Looking through the code, you should probably also use the `var` keyword to limit the scope of your variables `prev`, `next` and `s`. The current code behaves erratically if anything else other than up and down is pressed.

Comment: By the way, Yi, thanks for sharing the link to jsFiddle...I'd never heard of it before but I can see it being very handy in the future